# How to run mesos on Cent OS 7

Tags: linux, centos7, mesos

first i download dependencies

```
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"

sudo yum install -y python-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-md5 apr-devel subversion-devel apr-util-devell
```

second i download mesos

```
 wget http://www.apache.org/dist/mesos/0.23.0/mesos-0.23.0.tar.gz
```

then i want to start the mesos-master

```
 ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=192.168.168.188 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

and it tell me

```
 ./bin/mesos-master.sh: command not found
```

so i go to the dir of mesos/bin,  then i find there is no file named `mesos-master.sh` or `mesos-slave.sh` , I just see that all the files are named with suffix `sh.in`..like `mesos-master.sh.in` , `mesos-slave.sh.in`

Please tell me how could i start it ?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to build Mesos. Please follow steps listed in Building Mesos section of [getting started guide] (http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hartem already mentioned you should build Mesos following the instructions in the [starter guide](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted). Another option could be the mesosphere mesos packages (also available for CentOS 7): see https://mesosphere.com/downloads/